# Remove unwanted "footer" from react web-application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

**Edit:** Solved it, just added height in my css :D

In my react app I have noticed that I have this kind of "footer" on my page. It seems to be outside the body, and I cannot find why its there or how to remove it. I insert a picture what it looks like. **Does anyone know how I can solve this?** I inserted a picture below.

[Figure of the unwanted "footer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdHIt.jpg)

And just to add, if I make the body-smaller, this "footer" will fill up so it together with the body will fill the screen. However, if my body covers the screen, this box is still present..

CSS- for main-page

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #060405;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-size: 60px;
}


code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


a:link, a:visited {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  color: #b38a1b;
}
a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: none;
}


#page-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Main.js

```
function Main() {
  
    return (
        <HashRouter>
        <div className="App" id="outer-container">
            <Menu pageWrapId={'page-wrap'} outerContainerId={'outer-container'}>
              

            <NavLink exact to="/" className="menu-item"> HOME </NavLink>
                
            <NavLink to="/biography" className="menu-item"> BIOGRAPHPY </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/discography" className="menu-item"> DISCOGRAPHY </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/shows" className="menu-item"> SHOWS </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/photos" className="menu-item"> PHOTOS </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/videos" className="menu-item"> VIDEO </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/merch" className="menu-item"> MERCH </NavLink>

            <NavLink to="/contact" className="menu-item"> CONTACT </NavLink>
              
            </Menu>
       
      
          <div className="links">
          <a target="_blank" href=" "><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSpotify} /></a>
          <a target="_blank" href=" "><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faYoutube} /></a>
          <a target="_blank" href=" "><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faItunes} /></a>
          <a target="_blank" href=" "><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} /></a>
          <a target="_blank" href=" "><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} /></a>
          <a target="_blank" href=" "><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter} /></a>

          </div>

          <div className="content" id="page-wrap">

          
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/discography" component={Disc}/>
          {/* TODO
            <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
           */}  
          </div>
        </div>
       </HashRouter>
    );
  
}
 
export default Main;
```

Comment: Can you go to inspect and select the element?  From there, figure out what element it is and do whatever you need to do in the HTML/CSS.  Also, it would be great to post the HTML and CSS that you're working with.

Comment: That's the problem, the inspector does not seem to even "see" this, same in both firefox and in chrome..

Comment: Wait, is this your code?  If so, surely you can see the element within your code, correct?

Comment: Yes it is, or do you refer to above? Or that should be able to inspect my own code?

Comment: @AttemptedMastery I found the problem, I just had to specify my body to take up the entire height!